# EmguCV on Visual Studio 2017, cannot build example solution

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I downloaded the latest EmguCV example (3.2) on https://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/files/ as intructed by the tutorial on http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation, but I get the two following build errors for each project:

```
Task host node exited prematurely. Diagnostic information may be found in files in the temporary files directory named MSBuild_*.failure.txt.
```

(No MSBuild_*.failure.txt is to be found)

```
The "GenerateResource" task's outputs could not be retrieved from the "FilesWritten" parameter. Object does not match target type.  Emgu.CV.UI
```

I have followed the tutotial, but there must be a step missing. I installed the C++ redistributable, but no luck. I haven't installed anything else.

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your system locale? This can happen if it is set to a slightly unusual setting, as Emgu CV is very sensitive to this. I had to alter mine to English (US) to get it all to work.

Comment: That solved it! Now there's only the dreaded cvextern not found error left, although tutorial was followed. Pretty hard to get right.